# My Submit button on Wordpress Contact form is not sending

Tags: php, css, wordpress

So i just created a wp website, now my problem is the Contact Form 7 submit button does not send the form. Here is my code, im not sure where i messed it up.

[text* text-451 class:form-group placeholder "Name"]  [email* email-106 class:form-group placeholder "Email"]             Send Message *Get answers to common questions through our help center.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Go to contact form 7

Step 2: Select your form

Step 3: Click on Mail tab
[image: Step 3]

Step 4: Add your tags ad email where u want to receive the email.[image: Step 4]

Comment: Ok thank you, let me try that and see how it works out.